# Dynamic Variables and Arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a variable that is dynamic and updates once every day from a cache file, but when I wish to display the variable it pulls nothing although my cache file has the information stored.

This is an example of what I am trying to do...

```
$var1 = "1"; // Dynamic info that is previously pulled from the cache file. 
$var2 = array (
"0" => "2",
"1" => "3" );
```

Now I want to display the content of a certain part of the array...

```
echo "Test ".$var2['$var1'];
```

This is meant to output: Test 3

And if $var1 was a 0 it would output: Test 2

I have tried this many other ways, including changing the ' to ", or not even including them, it either displays a PHP error or it displays nothing apart from the "Test" text.

EDIT#1:
Ok, so this is to explain what I am doing a little bit better.

First I pull from a file and replace anything that comes with it that I don't need..

```
$myFile = "http://someserver.com/afile.txt";
$lines = file($myFile);
$ngender = preg_replace('/Gender=/', '', $lines[3]);
```

Now, I know that the above code works fine, its when I get to the array that I have problems..

```
$ngen = array (
1 => "Male",
2 => "Female"
);
```

Then I use $ngen[$ngender]; to store it into the xml file, but it don't store anything. This is actually I am trying to do before I store it into the xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
echo "Test ".$var2[$var1];
```

$var1 is a variable so it should no be in ''.

Comment: I have tried that, but I get the following error: Warning: Illegal offset type

Comment: Are you sure your $var1 is not an object or array in your original code? This is what PHP manual says about this error: 'Arrays and objects can not be used as keys. Doing so will result in a warning: Illegal offset type.'

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. Not all PHP arrays are associative. The following is valid and more efficient:

   ```
   $var2 = array(1 => "Male", 2 => "Female");
   ```
2. Variable names don't need to be stringified inside of statements. Your specific problem is caused because `'$var2'` would evaluate to the literal string `$var2`, while `"$var2"` would evaluate to `"1"`.

So the correct code:

```
$var1 = "1"; // Dynamic info that is previously pulled from the cache file.
$var2 = array(1 => "Male", 2 => "Female");

echo "Test ".$var2[$var1];
```

---

The error you've posted on the other answer's comment suggest that $var1 isn't what you think it is. Make sure.

Comment: But that still don't help me with my specific problem, I'll try to explain it a bit better.... the way contains this "1" => "Male", "2" => "Female"

Comment: The code I've posted works perfectly for me. Please, do explain a bit better.

Comment: the array contains this "1" => "Male", "2" => "Female"

Comment: $var1 displays 1 or 2 correctly without the array, but because my cache files stores either a 1 or 2, I need to convert it into what it actually is, for example, this is what I have....    $var1 = $player_gender; // Dynamic info that is previously pulled from the cache file.
    $var2 = array (1 => "Male", 2 => "Female");

    echo "Test ".$var2[$var1];

Comment: Try `var_dump()`ing it. If you get the error you've posted, you have something else in there.

Comment: Ok, I have tried that and I get this "object(SimpleXMLElement)#44 (1) { [0]=> string(2) "1 " }" the part of the xml cache file I am pulling from is <gender>1</gender> and then I do $player_gender = $xml->gender; to pass it in a variable... everything else works fine apart from this. I have even tried it without the variable and just using $xml->gender;

Comment: There's your problem. You can't use a `SimpleXMLElement` object as an array element. You need to extract the text value alone from it.

Comment: I have fixed my issue now, had to do a little bit of tweaking around. I am no longer using XML to cache stuff.